# Viewport Strech Mode Issues

Tags: resolution, godot

I'm using godot 3.1 on windows and i created new project with a 2d scene.

I selected the stretch mode viewport and the expand aspect options,

when I run the scene and try to resize the window, the viewport turns black.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known bug still in Godot's core as per a GitHub bug report

[Stretch Mode "viewport" causes screen not to update / black screen #23054](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/23054)

Also discussed here:
https://godotengine.org/qa/30600/black-screen-on-resize

I don't think there is a solution at the moment.